# Google Data Studio error - User Configuration Error This data source was improperly configured. Error ID: fb2ea24f

Tags: visualization, gcloud, looker-studio

I am trying to create a few visualizations from BigQuery data on Google Data Studio.

Following are the simulation steps:

1. Login into the BigQuery console
2. After running a query on the new Bigquery console, click the option "EXPLORE IN DATA STUDIO".
3. Create any chart or table
4. Click "SAVE" on the top right corner

This will generate an error:

> User Configuration Error This data source was improperly configured. Error ID: fb2ea24f

**Page with default table after clicking "EXPLORE IN DATA STUDIO"**:
[image: Image 1]

**Table disappears after clicking "SAVE"**:
[image: Image 2]

**Error details shown on pop-up after clicking "See Details"**:
[image: Image 3]